# MASM32 different

Tags: assembly, masm32

i'm a beginner in asm and i'm trying to figure out a kind of mistery for me.

I have this sample of code:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

      include \masm32\include\windows.inc
      include \masm32\include\user32.inc
      include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
      include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

      includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data

.code

function proc fileName:LPCTSTR
        LOCAL myoffset:DWORD

        ;various operations to initialize ecx...

        add ecx, 6
        mov myoffset, ecx
        xor ebx, ebx
        mov bx, word ptr [ecx]

        invoke  MessageBoxA, 0, str$ (ecx), str$ (ebx), MB_OK
        invoke  MessageBoxA, 0, str$ (myoffset), str$ (ebx), MB_OK
        invoke  MessageBoxA, 0, str$ (ebx), str$ (ebx), MB_OK

function endp

start:
        invoke function 
        push    0
    call    ExitProcess

end start
```

Which tell me thanks to the dialogs that:
ecx and myoffset have the same value
ebx contains 3.

But if instead of doing:

```
mov bx, word ptr [ecx]
```

I do:

```
mov bx, word ptr [myoffset]
```

The dialogs tell me that ebx contains something else (243 or around this)

But I absolutely don't understand why.

The code of course has been shorten to be more clear.

So... Did I miss something ?

Thanks :)

Comment: `mov bx, word ptr [ecx]` deferences `ecx` as a pointer, and `ecx` has not been set to anything valid. You are lucky it doesn't blow up. `mov bx, word ptr [myoffset]` correctly fetches the value of the local variable. It's hard to follow what contains what from your description.

Comment: It has been set valid before, i just erased from the sample as it doesn't directly concern my problem, but I will edit to precise it

Comment: Writing `various operations` doesn't tell us much. Note that `mov bx, word ptr [ecx]` will **only** load the value from `myoffset` **if** `ecx` is the address of `myoffset`. We need to see the code to verify how it is set up. PS: you are not reading some book, are you? I have a feeling of deja vu :)

Comment: Well I can add some code but the fact is that the value of ecx has been checked and is correct, it contains an address in a mapped file.

ecx is not the address of myoffset. I was assuming that after the line:

mov myoffset, ecx

ecx and myoffset should be equals. and the messageBoxes tell me that they are.

Reading books ? Hmm sometimes, what do you mean ? xD

Comment: If `ecx` is just some random pointer then `mov myoffset, ecx` just stores that random pointer into the local variable `myoffset`. `mov bx, [ecx]` loads the data from wherever random place `ecx` points to. `mov bx, [myoffset]` loads the value of `myoffset`, which is the pointer itself, it does not dereference it.

Comment: "loads the value of myoffset, which is the pointer itself, it does not dereference it" why not :O
is my syntax wrong ?

Comment: `myoffset` is already a pointer, it is probably something like `[ebp-4]` . So you really have `mov bx, [ebp-4]` and you'd want `mov bx, [[ebp-4]]` (double dereference). x86 is CISC, but that's not allowed unfortunately. You will need two steps to do two derefences. PS: even simple labels are just addresses, hence pointers.

Comment: ecx and myoffset are both supposed to be pointers.

in my mind the C equivalent of:
add ecx, 6
mov myoffset, ecx
xor ebx, ebx
mov bx, word ptr [ecx]

is:

char *ecx = ....; // whatever
ecx = ecx + 6;
char *myoffset = ecx;
//i skip the xor :p
char bx = *ecx;

mov bx, word ptr [ecx] : char bx = *ecx;
mov bx, word ptr [myoffset] : char bx = *offset;

if so, the value of bx in the two last lines should be the same, right ?

Comment: sorry for the bad indent :p

Comment: Since `myoffset` is a local variable the assembler addresses it relative to the frame or the stack pointer. Even if you type `myoffset` it is going to be something like `[ebp-4]`. It already needs one dereferencing that the assembler hides from you because you used a high level directive.

Comment: so the **mov bx, word ptr [myoffset]** line is incorrect I guess. what would be the correct version ?

Comment: There is none, you have to do it in 2 steps. `mov ebx, [myoffset]; mov bx, [ebx]`. Assuming it's pointing to a 16 bit integer. The pointer is still 32 bit though, hence the first load is 32 bit.

Comment: okay it seems to work. but I don't get why I have to do that. myoffset contains the same thing than ecx, and i only dereference ecx once. what is the difference ?

Comment: Assembler doesn't have "variables" like C. When you write in C: `a = 5`, you are doing in assembler `mov [A],5` and `A` in assembler is pointer into memory (`&a` equivalent in C). The C `a` equivalent doesn't exist, or it's more like C: `a = *a_ptr` Asm: `[A]` where `A == a_ptr`. So `mov myoffset,ecx` is already some highlevel mumbojumbo hiding the real machine code from you.

Comment: And that `mov ebx, [myoffset]; mov bx, [ebx]` should be: `mov ebx, [myoffset]; movzx bx, word ptr [ebx]` to clear upper 16b of `ebx` during fetch of value.

Comment: And probably the most confusing thing about that source is `mov myoffset, ecx` .. the MASM/TASM allows this (compiling it as store into memory even without `[]`), but I don't like it, rather use the `mov [myoffset], ecx` so it's immediately visible the instruction is referencing memory content and you can't read it by accident as just simple `mov` manipulating only values.

Comment: Okay I got it, thanks a lot for your explainations